# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.filter') - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am new to React/programming and having trouble fetching/displaying data. My code returns the error below. Thanks for your help in advance.

**TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.filter')**

```
  import useFetch from 'react-fetch-hook'

  const { data } = useFetch('http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories')

  const locations = props.navigation.getParam('locationId')

  const displayedCategories = data.filter(      // ERROR HERE
    cat => cat.locId.indexOf(locations) >= 0
  )

  const renderGridItem = itemData => {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        image={itemData.item.image}
        title={itemData.item.title}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      data={displayedCategories}
      renderItem={renderGridItem}
    />
  )
}
```

[image: JSON from http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories]

Comment: console your data first then work with that

Comment: Did you check if http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories responding in a valid manner? I mean with Postman etc?

Comment: Can u show the response of http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories

Comment: The address is showing valid JSON data. I'm fetching it from my local MySQL server.

Answer (score 2):

`useFetch` returns you a `isLoading` flag along with data which you must use to show a loading indicator till the data is available

```
const { isLoading, data } = useFetch('http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories');
 if(isLoading) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>
 }
 const locations = props.navigation.getParam('locationId')

  const displayedCategories = data.filter(
    cat => cat.locId.indexOf(locations) >= 0
  )

  const renderGridItem = itemData => {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        image={itemData.item.image}
        title={itemData.item.title}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      data={displayedCategories}
      renderItem={renderGridItem}
    />
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting this error this time: "TypeError: cat.locId.indexOf is not a function. (In 'cat.locId.indexOf(locations)', 'cat.locId.indexOf' is undefined)"

Comment: Could you please log data before data.filter and check what is the returned value

Answer (score 1):

I think at start there is no data so please use default assign

```
  const { data = [] } = useFetch('http://192.168.2.94:3000/list-categories')
```

**UPDATE**

```
  const displayedCategories = data.filter(
    cat => cat && cat.locId && cat.locId.indexOf(locations) >= 0
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting this error this time: "TypeError: cat.locId.indexOf is not a function. (In 'cat.locId.indexOf(locations)', 'cat.locId.indexOf' is undefined)"

Comment: @Gezginrocker please change **displayedCategories** function